# Replace all that match [.*] in ![CDATA[xxx]] without replacing CDATA

Tags: java, regex, scala

I'm trying to remove all [.*] in a string but without removing ![CDATA[xxx]].
I'm expecting the following result

```
"""![CDATA[please remove[macro]]]"""
    .replaceAll("""(?<!CDATA)\[(?!CDATA).*\]""", "")
```

shouldBe

`![CDATA[please remove]]`

But the result is

`![CDATA[please remove`

Comment: XML isn't a good fit for regular expressions so using a proper parser might be the better option.

Comment: Btw, how is your call to `replaceAll( regex, "")` meant to add that `<AdTitle>` etc.?

Comment: Sorry I copy too much stuff

Comment: What can be the content of "macro"?  In particular, is it safe to assume that it will not contain the closing square brace character (']')?

Comment: @JohnBollinger, macro can only be word characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already said XML isn't a good fit for regex but if your input *always* looks like `![CDATA[something [macro] something ... ]]`, i.e. macros don't contain whitespace (which in most cases doesn't make sense anyways) and there aren't other strings that might look like macros you could do something like this:

```
String replaced = "![CDATA[please remove[macro]]]".replaceAll("(?<!CDATA)\\[\\w+\\]", "" );
```

Breakdown of the expression `(?<!CDATA)\[\w+\]`:

- `(?<!CDATA)` is a negative look-behind, i.e. the match must not directly preceded by `CDATA`. Is is meant to prevent that CDATA elements without macros match)
- `\[\w+\]` matches any sequence of word characters (`\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) surrounded by square brackets, e.g. it would match `[please_remove]` but *not* `[please remove]`.

Using that expression you'd get the following matches on `![CDATA[ somthing [macro] somthing [another_macro]]] ... [macro_outside] ... [not a macro] ... ![CDATA[empty]]`:

- `[macro]`
- `[another_macro]`
- `[macro_outside]`

But let me reiterate once again: this only works if you know what the input strings can look like or don't care if it doesn't work when they don't match your requirements (if you accept any input there are for sure situations that don't match as you want them to - since XML is an irregular language).

Comment: Unfortunately not CDATA can contains macro and it does not always contains macro

Comment: Thanks for you fast and complete answer !
My string is a full XML, I'm not sure to understand your warnings, do you have an example that can help me understand?

Comment: @MaxenceCramet with the quite simple expression what could happen is that a user enters some text that looks like a macro but isn't meant to be one. The warnings on XML + regex are more general: in XML you can nest elements in various ways (and do other things) and thus you could end up in situations where a regex doesn't match everything your want or matches the wrong things (as an example imagine a CDATA that contains XML which in turn contains it's own CDATA - believe me, I've seen such things :) ).